# How to acquire SAML token using OBO flow in Azure

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, openid-connect, saml-2.0

I have an enterprise app in Azure (SAML SSSO enabled) that gives me a SAML assertion with group info in it. And I use that saml assertion in third party service. This flow works as expected with normal user (i.e. using email/password).

Now I would like some service account/principle to be able to use the same third party service as human users. And from my reading it seems like On behalf of flow is the correct way [OnBehalf of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#saml-assertions-obtained-with-an-oauth20-obo-flow) So, I created a new app registration and created the secrets to use, I got the first token as follows:

```
# python
payload = {
   "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": ["<app_id_of_saml_application>/.default"],
}
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
response = requests.post(authority, data=payload)
access_token =  response.json()["access_token"]
```

The decoded access token contains the roles that I exposed from SAML SSO enabled app as well as the `aud` claim points to SAML application. Now I am trying to use this token to get a SAML assertion as below.

```
# python
payload = {
        "client_id": saml_client_id,
        "client_secret": saml_client_secret,
        "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        "scope": ["<app_id_of_saml_application>/.default"],
        "assertion": access_token, # Access token from previous step
        "requested_token_use": "on_behalf_of",
        "requested_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:saml2",
    }
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
response = requests.post(authority, data=payload)
```

I get the following error:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found.
```

I think this is because may be I am not exposing correct roles/permissions from the SAML application. Have anyone stumbled upon this issue ? I have added the normal app (that wants to exchange the token) to the list of trusted applications and known applications in SAML application too.

Please let me know if anyone have solved this issue.

I was expecting the second call would give me a SAML token.

Answer (score 0):

Applications with custom signing keys can't be used as middle-tier APIs in the OBO flow. **This includes enterprise applications configured for single sign-on.** If the middle-tier API uses a custom signing key, the downstream API won't be able to validate the signature of the access token that is passed to it. This will result in an error because tokens signed with a key controlled by the client can't be safely accepted.